# How to handle a Button Click in C#

Tags: c#, windows, events, button

I am making a windows application with C# and I can't seem to figure out how to create a Click event handler on a button. None of the examples I have seen work and I don't understand why. Can someone please show and explain how to handle button clicks in this situation. Thanks!

Comment: Put a button on your form in the designer. Double click on it. Have fun.

Comment: Search for tutorials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the click event to the button use

```
myButton.Click += new EventHandler(MyClickEvent);
```

Then to define the event use

```
private void MyClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    txtMyTextbox.Text = "Hello World!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(button1_Click);
```

refer to this link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfty2w4e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx