# How to trigger button1 click & execute some more code in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling

I have 2 Buttons on form: button1 & button2.
Button 2 should execute code under button1 as well as some extra code in button2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle a Button Click in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30586000/how-to-handle-a-button-click-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two buttons click events like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something else
}
```

You can execute the second button event from the first button click like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do something
    button2_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Also you can have the code you want to execute in both buttons on a void and just call that void from the click events of the buttons.

Comment: `RoutedEventArgs` is not WinForms class

Comment: I modified it to `EventArgs`